# How to remove multiple rows via checkbox

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and I need to be able to delete the selected rows by  checkbox. How can I delete multiple rows from the database? I am using Thymeleaf as view.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <table class="table" id="tableImport">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                <th scope="col">Debt Age Rule</th>
                <th scope="col">Reminder</th>
                <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                <th scope="col">Reorder</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr th:each="configCampaign:${listConfigCampaigns}">
                <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">
                </td>
                <td th:text="${configCampaign.debtagerule}"></td>
                <td th:text="${configCampaign.remindebttype}"></td>
                <td th:text="'Every '+${configCampaign.every} + ' ' + ${configCampaign.unit}"></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
         <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="- Remove Selected Action(s)"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

This table shows me data from an arrayList in memory, nothing with a database, I need to remove those selected objects from the array. At the moment I have my controller like this

[image]

**Entity**

```
private int configid;
private String debtagerule;
private String remindebttype;
private int every;
private String unit;
private boolean selected;

//getters and setters
```

In addition to the above, this is the controller with which I am currently working

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/deleteConfigureCampaign")
public String deleteConfig(@ModelAttribute ConfigCampaign configCampaign, Model model) {
    listConfigCampaigns.remove(configCampaign);
    return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Controller` and `Service`. Remove item from database or temparary remove from page?

Comment: @GetMapping("/deleteConfigureCampaign")
public String deleteConfig(@ModelAttribute ConfigCampaign configCampaign, Model model) {
    listConfigCampaigns.remove(configCampaign);
    return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
}
this is my controller, the idea is to remove temporary objects

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, You have to use `JpaRepository<>` for delete data from database and need to understand structure of Spring Boot project.

Here is sturcture of Spring Boot project:

**`Entity` -> `Repository` -> `Service` -> `Controller` -> `View`**.

Here down is code:

**Entity**

```
@Table(name = "config_master")
public class ConfigCampaign {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer configid;
    private String debtagerule;
    private String remindebttype;
    private Integer every;
    private String unit;
    private boolean selected;
    // Constructor, Getter and Setter
}
```

**Repository**

- **Use of `@Modifying` annotation:** It is used to enhance the `@Query` annotation so that we can execute not only SELECT queries, but also INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and even DDL queries

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepo extends JpaRepository<ConfigCampaign, Integer>{
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DELETE FROM config_master WHERE configid IN(?1)")
    void delConfig(List<Integer> configId);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class PojoServiceImpl{
    
    @Autowired
    private ConfigRepo configRepo;

    @Override
    public void delConfig(Integer[] configId) {
        configRepo.delConfig(Arrays.asList(configId));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
// Show table of Config Campaign
@RequestMapping(value = "/showconfig", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getConfig(Model mdl)
{
    List<ConfigCampaign> getConfig = pojoService.getAllConfig();
    mdl.addAttribute("config", getConfig);
    return "showConfigCampaign";
}

// Delete item from Config Campaign
@RequestMapping(value = "/delcampaign", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteConfig(@RequestParam("cid") Integer[] configId)
{
    pojoService.delConfig(configId);
    return "redirect:/showconfig";
}
```

**showConfigCampaign**

You have to add `configData.configid` in checkbox.

```
<form th:action="@{/delcampaign}" th:object="${sconfig}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table" style="text-align: center">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Remove</th>
                      <th scope="col">Debt Age Rule</th>
                      <th scope="col">Reminder</th>
                      <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="configData: ${config}">
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cid" th:value="${configData.configid}"/></td>
                      <td th:text="${configData.debtagerule}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${configData.remindebttype}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${configData.every}"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Users" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```